# I need help on this data file to be edited in SOM_PAK format

Tags: matlab, som

I am working on Self Organizing Map (SOM) Implementation and I have a microarray dataset which I am trying to read in using some_read_data function, but I keep having an errors when I edit it to have it in SOM_PAK form which is recognise by SOM for reading such as:

> ??? Error using ==> somtoolbox\som_read_data.m Only 69 vector
>   components on input file data line 1 (dimension is 70)
>
> Error in ==> SomMainFunction at 3 sD = som_read_data('B_r2.txt');

But, when I try to read the data without editing which is [the original file](http://rapidshare.com/files/376239367/DLBCL.txt.html) (Editor: **DEAD LINK!**), it indicates "Data read OK", but I have the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> unknown Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
>   options.
>
> Error in ==> somtoolbox\som_bmus.m at 189 Bmus =
>   zeros(dlen,length(which_bmus));
>
> Error in ==> somvis\somvis_p_matrix.m at 41
>       [dummy dists] = som_bmus (dat, dat, 2:datlen);
>
> Error in ==> SomMainFunction at 16 [pheight rad_real perc] =
>   somvis_p_matrix(sM,sD);

You can get the datafile from [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/376239367/DLBCL.txt.html) (Editor: **DEAD LINK!**)
you can also download the toolbox from [here](http://www.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/dm/somvis-matlab/index.html#Installation).

I need someone to help me correct this data for me and put it in SOM_PAK format. I have tried getting it in SOM_PAK format, but it still giving me errors.

Comment: Provide a link where to download the toolbox you are using from. Also the file to download is DLBCL.txt, but you are reading B_r2.txt.

Comment: Here is the to download the toolbox link:file:///C:/MATLAB7/TestingSOM/index.html#Installation

This DLBCL.txt is the original file which reads Ok with your script, but when i run it on the main function, it has memory error.

the B_r2.txt is my edited file which still gives error. Here is the link to where you can download B_r2.txt:http://rapidshare.com/files/376457253/B_r2.txt.html

thanks

Comment: B_r2.txt is my edited file which still gives error. Here is the link to where you can download B_r2.txt:http://rapidshare.com/files/376457253/B_r2.txt.html 
I am Using Matlab 7.0 R14 on Win XP

Comment: Still no link to download the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

In B_r2.txt your first column is not the data, just row numbers, delete it. The number in the first row should be number of columns. Why it's 47?